# Replace specific NAs with values from another row by column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I hope this is not a trivial question, but I did not find a solution on other queries.

My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id= c("A","B",NA,NA,"C","A", "D",NA ), id2 = c("11","22","11","44","33",NA, NA, NA), id3 = c("a","b",NA,NA,NA,"a","a","b"))
print(df)
#      id  id2  id3
# 1    A   11    a
# 2    B   22    b
# 3 <NA>   11 <NA>
# 4 <NA>   44 <NA>
# 5    C   33 <NA>
# 6    A <NA>    a
# 7    D <NA>    a
# 8 <NA> <NA>    b
```

My concern is with `id` that is my key identifier but it has some inconsistent recordings. I would like to use information on `id2` and `id3` to make it consistent.

There are two main manipulations that I need to do:
First, I have some missing observations in `id`. I would like to replace the NAs in `id` taking the value of id in other rows that have the same  `id2` or `id3`. The data should look something like this:

```
#     id  id2  id3 id_f
# 1    A   11    a    A
# 2    B   22    b    B
# 3 <NA>   11 <NA>    A # id_f: replaced NA in id, with "A" because when id2=11, id=A (in row 1) 
# 4 <NA>   44 <NA> <NA>
# 5    C   33 <NA>    C
# 6    A <NA>    a    A
# 7    D <NA>    a    D
# 8 <NA> <NA>    b    B # id_f: replaced NA of id, with "B" because when id3=b, id=B (in row 2)
```

The basic idea is that I have multiple indicators that allow me to individuate `id`. If `id2` (or `id3`) are identical so should `id`.
For instance, in row 3, `id2="11"`. `id2` is equal to 11 also in row 1. meaning that they refer to the same `id`. Hence I replace the missing value of row 3 in `id` with A (corresponding to the value of id when id2=11). The same line of reasoning is used for row 8 and id3.

The second manipulation address a different issue: sometimes `id` is wrongly reported. For instance row 1, 6 and 7 all have the same value of `id3` (a), but they have different values of `id` (A, A, and D respectively). In these cases, I would like to modify my identifier (i create a new column id_f2) only keeping the `id` value that that occurs the most. The final dataset should look like this:

```
#     id  id2  id3 id_f id_f2
# 1    A   11    a    A     A
# 2    B   22    b    B     B 
# 3 <NA>   11 <NA>    A     A # modified as in id_f
# 4 <NA>   44 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
# 5    C   33 <NA>    C     C
# 6    A <NA>    a    A     A
# 7    D <NA>    a    D     A # Here id_f2=A because when id3=a id=A in the majority of cases (row 1 and 6, hence the recorded value of id=D is incorrect.) 
# 8 <NA> <NA>    b    B     B # modified as in id_f
```

If anyone knows a compact way to do this I would sincerely appreciate it

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: People might offer solutions in base R, data.table, and dplyr. Which would you prefer?

Comment: Yes, in your dataset whenever id is NA, id2 and id3 are not equal
Also is NA a character "NA"or is it NA?

Comment: data.table would be the best solution because I have a large dataset and speed is important. but if there is a more economic solution (in terms of line of codes), I would be happy to try this as well.

Comment: I have updated the question to adress your queries: the character "NA" indicates missing observations NA. By "id2 or id3 are identical" I mean that when the values in `id2` or `id3` are the same across different rows, so should be the value for `id`. Hence when `id` is NA, but `id2` or `id3` have the same values of other rows where  `id` is not NA, i can replace the NA with the corresponding value. I hope this is clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setDT(df)

# first part, id_f: ####
df[!is.na(id3),id_f:=na.omit(id)[1],by=id3]
df[!is.na(id2),id_f:=na.omit(id)[1],by=id2]
df[!is.na(id),id_f:=id]


# second part, id_f2: ####
df[!is.na(id3),
   n1:=.N,
   by=.(id3,id)][!is.na(id3),id_f2:=id[(order(-n1))][1],by=id3]
df[!is.na(id2),
   n1:=.N,
   by=.(id2,id)][!is.na(id2),id_f2:=id[(order(-n1))][1],by=id2]

# clean up temporary field: ####
df$n1 <- NULL

# result ####
print(df)
 
#      id  id2  id3 id_f id_f2
# 1:    A   11    a    A     A
# 2:    B   22    b    B     B
# 3: <NA>   11 <NA>    A     A
# 4: <NA>   44 <NA> <NA>  <NA>
# 5:    C   33 <NA>    C     C
# 6:    A <NA>    a    A     A
# 7:    D <NA>    a    D     A
# 8: <NA> <NA>    b    B     B
```

Comment: Great this is exactly what I was looking for! Just one follow up question, would you mind explaining in a couple of lines what are you doing so that I will be able to replicate this in sliglty different situations? thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: the issue with this approach is that when i apply it to the main database the following error emerges `Supplied 30224 items to be assigned to group 1 of size 31704 in column`. do you know how to go about it?

Comment: this error most probably means that in your table there were records with identical `id2` but different `id`. You need to reflect this in your example and explain how you want to solve those cases.

Comment: You can try to replace `id:=na.omit(id)` with `id:=na.omit(id)[1]` - but again, I can't be sure, without seeing more relevant example, whether this is what you needed

Comment: I realized what is the issue, and solved. I have however a follow up question. How can I integrate the code above to ensure that it selects the one with most occurrences? I am updating the question

Comment: @Alex please see my answer. Hope it gives you some inspiration

Comment: I have updated my answer, see if it's what you wanted

Comment: @Alex if any of the answers is a solution to your question, mark it as a solution - so that other readers can see that it is solved. Otherwise feel free to update if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

Economic in lines of code is subjective, hence a `tidyverse` solution

You can also use `dplyr` verbs (of my answer) on `dt` with https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr

It is still unclear to me what you want, because there is never a single rule available for transforming a `NA` column. What I am essentially doing is creating a key-value df which you join to your original df

```
library(tidyverse)

# Split your df into two parts
not_na <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
df_na <- df[!complete.cases(df), ]

# 1st I convert the df to long format
df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(!id, names_to = "ïds" , values_to = "value") 
# As I understand a criteria for missing value imputation is to use the max value
df_long_max <- df_long %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(which.max(table(value)))

# removing the NA rows 
df_long_max <- df_long_max %>% select(c(id,value)) %>% drop_na() %>% ungroup()
# The below df has a key-value combinations, use these to impute
df_long_max <- df_long_max %>% rename(key=id)

# Do a left join
df_na_joined <- left_join(df_na, df_long_max, 
                    by = c("id2" = "value"))

# Now you can replace
df_na_joined  <- df_na_joined %>% mutate(id3=case_when(is.na(id3)~key))
```

Now you can `rbind` with the `not_na` dataframe.

Please beware our solutions are only valid for the use-case you posted here. You will have to take inspiration from these solutions and adapt it to your real problem

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I fear this does not address my answer. indeed i do have `id2` and `id3` equal when `id` is NA, in row 3 and 6. in both case it is equal to row one. doe this clarify the issue?